# Group similar values associated with a name in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

In given table we have 2 column ActivityId and **Name and output** what we want to see is Name `ActivityId` and `count` of that ActivityId , multiple activity are attached with one Name.

Answer (score 0):

You need `grouping` (i.e. `GROUP BY`) clause :

```
select ActivityId, name, count(*) as ActivityIdCount
from table t
group by ActivityId, name;
```